# Classification of index in Phase Portaits

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot, tikz-cd

I am trying to make the following graphs horizontally, I used the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347401/248335) as a basis:
[image]

**input:**

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}

\tikzset
  {every pin/.style={pin edge={<-}}
  ,>=stealth
  ,flow/.style=
    {decoration=
      {markings
      ,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}
      }
    ,postaction={decorate}
    }
  ,flow/.default=0.5
  }
\newcommand\inlayscale{}
\newcommand\inlaycaption[1]{{\sffamily\scriptsize#1}}
\newcommand\newinlay[4][0.18]%
  {\renewcommand\inlayscale{#1}%
   \newsavebox#2%
   \savebox#2%
     {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        #4\\[-1ex]
        \inlaycaption{#3}\\[-1ex]
      \end{tabular}%
     }%
  }
\newcommand\inlay[1]{\usebox{#1}}
\newcommand\Tr{\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}}

\newinlay\saddle{index $-1$}%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
     \foreach \sx in {+,-}
      {\draw[flow] (\sx4,0) -- (0,0);
       \draw[flow] (0,0) -- (0,\sx4);
       \foreach \sy in {+,-}
         \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {2.8/0.3/0.7/0.6,3.9/0.4/1.3/1.1}
           \draw[flow] (\sx\a,\sy\b)
              .. controls (\sx\c,\sy\d) and (\sx\d,\sy\c)
              .. (\sx\b,\sy\a);
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }


\newinlay[0.15]\centre{index $0$}%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
     \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
     \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
     \foreach \r in {1,2,3} \draw[flow=0.63] (\r,0) arc (0:-360:\r cm);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }


\newinlay\source{index $+1$}%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
     \foreach \sx in {+,-}
      {\draw[flow] (0,0) -- (\sx4,0);
       \draw[flow] (0,0) -- (0,\sx4);
       \foreach \sy in {+,-}
         \foreach \a/\b in {2/1,3/0.44}
           \draw[flow,domain=0:\sx\a] plot (\x, {\sy\b*\x*\x});
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\newinlay[0.15]\dipolo{index $+2$}%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1}
  \draw (0,\x/5) circle [radius=\x/5+1/5];
  \draw (-1,-1/5) -- (1,-1/5);
\end{tikzpicture}
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  % n diagram


  % inlays
  \node at (-4,0) {\inlay\saddle};
  \node at (-2,0) {\inlay\saddle};
  \node at (0,0) {\inlay\source};
  \node at (2,0){\inlay\centre};
  \node at (4,0) {\inlay\source};
  \node at (6,0) {\inlay\dipolo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**output:**
[image]

I know that it doesn't look anything like what I want, for example the dates are very rough, I would like them to be more visible (more fluid). I'll keep trying and any updates I'll post here. Any kind of help I will be very grateful.

Comment: Dates? Dots? Could you explain a bit more what you are not happy with and describe how you would like it to be?

Comment: It's not just that, as you can see my graphs don't look like what I need. For example, I would like the dates to be a little smaller, I feel that being large you cannot really appreciate the flow and the shape that is expected within the phase plane. If you zoom in on the center graph you will see that the dates are not well centered so it cannot be seen well. I have only tried to modify something that I saw in an answer, and give it the form that I want so I am stuck.

Comment: I don't know what is meant by a "Date" in this context.

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is bad: I mean the arrows

Comment: You may try `mark=between positions #1 and #2 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=#3]{latex}}` in your `flow/.style` from my previous answer to you [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644721/140133).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `mark=between positions #1 and 0.99 step 1.5em with {\arrow{>} [scale=0.5]}` to your `decoration`, so the original source code works as previously,

I also created your `index = -2` design at `doubleSaddle`, not the best name. I drew it with colors so it is easier to understand how the lines with `control ..` are mirrored while preserving flow direction. I used [tikzedt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) to draw it by moving nodes and controls with mouse.

Your code for `index=0` and `index=1` were not the same from your original handraw. I didn't change them, I kept number as you wrote in the code.

Other index figures I just changed the `flow=<parameter>` in order to have a better result.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}

\tikzset
{every pin/.style={pin edge={<-}},
  >=stealth,
  flow/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions #1 and 0.99 step 1.5em with {\arrow{>} [scale=0.5]}
    }, postaction={decorate}
  },
  flow/.default=0.5
}
\newcommand\inlayscale{}
\newcommand\inlaycaption[1]{{\sffamily\scriptsize#1}}
\newcommand\newinlay[4][0.18]%
{\renewcommand\inlayscale{#1}%
  \newsavebox#2%
  \savebox#2%
  {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      #4\\[-1ex]
      \inlaycaption{#3}\\[-1ex]
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\inlay[1]{\usebox{#1}}
\newcommand\Tr{\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}}

\newinlay\doubleSaddle{index $-2$}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale,red]
    \foreach \sx in {+,-}{
      \draw[flow=0.1] (4,0) -- (-4,0);
      \draw[flow,blue!50!black] (0,0) -- (2,\sx3);
      \draw[flow=0.75,blue] (-2,\sx3) -- (0,0);
      
      \draw[flow=0.20,orange] (-1.7,\sx3)
      .. controls (-0.3,\sx1.2) and (0.3,\sx1.2)
      .. (1.7,\sx3);
      \draw[flow=0.20,green] (3.9,\sx0.2)
      .. controls (1.9,\sx0.2) and (0.8,\sx0.8)
      .. (2.1,\sx2.8);
      \draw[flow=0.20,green!50!black] (-2.1,\sx2.8)
      .. controls (-0.8,\sx0.8) and (-1.9,\sx0.2)
      .. (-3.9,\sx0.2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newinlay\saddle{index $-1$}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
    \foreach \sx in {+,-}
    {\draw[flow] (\sx4,0) -- (0,0);
      \draw[flow] (0,0) -- (0,\sx4);
      \foreach \sy in {+,-}
      \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {2.8/0.3/0.7/0.6,3.9/0.4/1.3/1.1}
      \draw[flow] (\sx\a,\sy\b)
      .. controls (\sx\c,\sy\d) and (\sx\d,\sy\c)
      .. (\sx\b,\sy\a);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newinlay[0.15]\centre{index $0$}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
    \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \foreach \r in {1,2,3} \draw[flow=0.1] (\r,0) arc (0:-360:\r cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newinlay\source{index $+1$}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inlayscale]
    \foreach \sx in {+,-}
    {\draw[flow] (0,0) -- (\sx4,0);
      \draw[flow] (0,0) -- (0,\sx4);
      \foreach \sy in {+,-}
      \foreach \a/\b in {2/1,3/0.44}
      \draw[flow,domain=0:\sx\a] plot (\x, {\sy\b*\x*\x});
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newinlay[0.15]\dipolo{index $+2$}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1}
    \draw[flow=0.1] (0,\x/5) circle [radius=\x/5+1/5];
    \draw (-1,-1/5) -- (1,-1/5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  % inlays
  \node at (-4,0) {\inlay\doubleSaddle};
  \node at (-2,0) {\inlay\saddle};
  \node at (0,0){\inlay\centre};
  \node at (2,0) {\inlay\source};
  \node at (4,0) {\inlay\dipolo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]